# Cannot implement Bean Validation API

Tags: java, api, rest, maven, validation

In reference to this tutorial: https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-validation-for-restful-services-with

I am trying to validate a POST request for a REST API using the Bean Validation API via Maven.

pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am trying to make it so that if the Feedback JSON being posted has no name, then it reads it as invalid.

Feedback.java

```
public class Feedback {
    
    @Size(min=2, message="Name should have at least 2 characters")
    private String name; // getter and setter below
```

Controller.java

```
    @PostMapping("/feedback")
    ResponseEntity<?> add(@Valid @RequestBody Feedback feedback) {
```

From the tutorial, it should be enough to annotate the field (@Size) and the post function (@Valid @RequestBody) however even though the project compiles, when making the post request, it accepts the empty name field as valid.

```
{
  "name": "",
```

What am I missing for this to work?

EDIT-1:

Tried to add this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Resulted in the following.

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.1.Final

org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.1.Final
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:524)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.collect.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:227)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.lambda$3(ProjectRegistryManager.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.lambda$1(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1370)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.MavenBuildSupport.update(MavenBuildSupport.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.managers.ProjectsManager$3.runInWorkspace(ProjectsManager.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:pom:7.0.1.Final from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:pom:7.0.1.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:240)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:pom:7.0.1.Final from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:pom:7.0.1.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:401)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: You are missing an implementation. You only have the API not an implementation like `hibernate-validator`.

Comment: I tried adding this dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/7.0.1.Final its failing to read or is missing artifacts

Comment: Please post the full error output....

Comment: Updated question with dependency and log

Comment: Hibernate validator 7.0.1 isn't supported, that uses JakartaEE and that isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the Spring Validation in your pom.xml .

```
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: I tried adding this dependency https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/2.4.3 its failing to read or is missing artifacts